# Layout: fixed text box on the left with scrollable MDL cards on the right

Tags: html, css, scroll, material-design, material-design-lite

I've been having an issue with fixing some text on two of my pages. I have a box on the left with some text in it, and two MDL cards on the right containing dialogues.

My issue is that as soon as I put a fixed position term in the CSS for the text, my cards overlap it and realign to the left. I tried to contain them but that didn't seem to be any help, maybe I did something incorrectly.

I like the way it looks as it is just now, but I would like the MDL cards to scroll independently. Again, probably an easy fix and something I've overlooked but heres what I have so far:

```
 <div class="mdl-layout__content">

        <main>

          <div class="boxed-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sed feugiat lectus. Phasellus maximus, ex nec bibendum volutpat, justo erat pellentesque massa, vel malesuada sem lectus tincidunt orci. Aenean eleifend est sit amet dapibus ullamcorper.
            Nam ornare finibus ex vitae interdum. Sed quis purus eros. Sed ut porttitor dolor, eget ultrices justo. Sed eu leo porta, mattis libero eu, sagittis metus. Vivamus nec lobortis nisi. Suspendisse posuere enim arcu, at interdum dui congue vitae.
            Aliquam vestibulum accumsan magna. Vivamus a arcu nunc. Cras euismod lacinia augue sed elementum. Phasellus dignissim semper mi at sollicitudin. Vivamus maximus semper nulla. Donec luctus, dolor non viverra aliquam, enim arcu imperdiet sem,
            et pretium dui ante ac lectus.
          </div>

          <div class="cards">


            <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
              <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"></h2>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                  <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button">View Product</button>

                  <dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog">
                      <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">Product 1</h3>
                      <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
                        <p>
                          This is an example of the Material Design Lite dialog component.
                          Please use responsibly.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
                        <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>

                      </div>
                    </dialog>
           </div>

              <div class="mdl-card__menu">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
              <div class="mdl-card__title">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"></h2>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                  <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-button dialog-button-1">View Product</button>

                  <dialog id="dialog-1" class="mdl-dialog">
                      <h3 class="mdl-dialog__title">Product 2</h3>
                      <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
                        <p>
                          This is an example of the Material Design Lite dialog component.
                          Please use responsibly.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
                        <button type="button" class="mdl-button">Close</button>

                      </div>
                    </dialog>

              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__menu">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </button>
              </div>
              <div class="mdl-card__menu">
                <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        </main>
```

CSS:

```
 .boxed-1{
      width: 40%;
      height: auto; 
      text-align: justify;
      display: flex;
      /* position: fixed; */
      vertical-align: center;
      padding: 15px;
      margin: 20px;
      background-color: #fff;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    }

    .mdl-layout__content main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: right;
    }

     .demo-card-wide.mdl-card {
      width: 100%;
      /* margin-left: 90%; */
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
      /* position: relative; */
    }

    .demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__title {
      color: #cccccc;
      height: 430px;
      background: url('images/placeholder.jpg') 0px;

    }

    .demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__menu {
      color: #fff;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.boxed-1` and `.cards` elements are holding the space for the left and right sections of your flex layout, so changing `.boxed-1` to `position: fixed` breaks the layout. Simple fix without changing your current approach too much would be to wrap your text in another `div` and set it to `position: fixed`, so `.boxed-1` still holds the space you want in your flex layout and the new `div` prevents the text from scrolling. You will need some additional css to ensure the new `div` doesn't overlap the other elements.

Example HTML:

```
<main>
  <div class="boxed-1">
    <div class="fixed">
      Lorem ipsum...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards">
    <!-- cards html -->
  </div>
</main>
```

Example CSS:

```
main {
  display: flex;
}

.boxed-1 {
  width: 30vw;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  text-align: justify;
}

.cards {
  width: 70vw;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  width: calc(30vw - 40px);
}
```